# It'd be nice to be able to unfollow a specific question I made that I don't want to get notifications from anymore

Tags: feature-request

In my case, I have a question I made almost 10 years ago that I still get comments and answers and get notified about them.
I don't want to block it or dissociate from it, I like it, I learned a lot from its answers and comments, but I moved on, I don't really want to be reminded about it anymore.
It's ok that people still find it relevant enough to answer or comment on it, though.
So It would be great if there was an option to unfollow specific questions. (like you disable notifications from posts on social networks)

Comment: Do you also not want to get rep notifications?

Comment: Would this also include notifications of edits to your post? (It sounds like 'no' but I wanted to check.)

Comment: Laurel, @BSMP That's right, no notifications at all related to a specific question.